# How do I create a laser pointer dot in Unity URP?

Tags: unity

I want to replicate the laser pointer dot as in RE4:

[image]

[Here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6bo-Y6hhyq8) that shows the laser in action.

I have tried to replicate it using a spotlight. The problem with the spotlight is that its size can only be controlled by its distance to the object. I'm struggeling really hard with keeping it at just the right distance.

Since this is such a big problem, I would first of all like to ask if a spotlight is the preferred way to create such a laser dot.

Thank you.

Comment: Presumably you considered using a [projector](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Projector.html) or decal placed at the end of a raycast (similar to how one would place a bullet hole, but with additive blending)?

Comment: @DMGregory I'm using the URP, so a projector isn't an option. I have not tried a decal yet. I will investigate on it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm now using a Screen Space Decal Shader that works with URP, specificially this one:

https://github.com/ColinLeung-NiloCat/UnityURPUnlitScreenSpaceDecalShader

I will update my answer with the details as soon as I have it completed. I'm still working on the details of an implementation.

Comment: This answer would be even better if it walked through the steps of how to use this to create the laser pointer effect.

Comment: @DMGregory I have updated my post accordingly.

Comment: "I will update my answer" - do you still have an update pending?

Comment: No, I have not worked on it yet any further.